# More Content Types to scan for Task Tags in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, comments, task

Is there a way I can add more Content Types to search for Task Tags in Eclipse?

At the moment there are several file types where it is handy to add a quick TODO comment, but they don't show up in my Task list, so they are easy to forget... I would for example like my SQL and Gradle files to be scanned so I get the TODO comments there in my Task list together with the rest. Is there any way to accomplish this?

[image: Task Tags dialog in Eclipse]

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like [bug 26849: "Add recognition of Task tags to all other editing types, not just Java"](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=26849), entered in November... 2002!

And its status is "help wanted".

Answer (score 0):

Create a new extension for the org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.taskscanner extension point, implementing org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.provisional.tasks.IFileTaskScanner .  The content type you specify will then appear in the page as an option.

Comment: hey, can you please add a little bit more info, what is to do. I hope, your answer is useful to add content types but i can't follow you.

Comment: This does require authoring a plug-in.  The extension point lets you tie an implementation of IFileTaskScanner to automatically be called when files of your content types are processed.  How you actually detect the tasks is up to your scanner implementation, this just makes sure that there's a _when_ for calling it.